# Creating a Python code to clear out folders in File Explorer

Tags: python, windows, delete-file, microsoft-file-explorer

I work as an IT help desk associate and have to constantly clear out disk space for VDIs. I want to write a code that can clear out specific folders all at once to save time. I wrote a code, but only have it to run one folder at a time. Is there a way for me to make it a function and just make variables for each path and have them all cleared at once. Sample:

```
import os

#path to delete
path = r"C:\Users\jwals\test test"

#will check if the path is a dir or not
if os.path.exists(path):
    
#iterating through subfolders
    for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(path):
        
        #checking for files
        for file in files:
            
            #file path
            file_path = os.path.join(root_folder, file)
            
            #delete the files in that path
            if not os.remove(file_path):
                   #will print if successful
                   print(f"{file_path} deleted successfully")
                   #unsuccessful message (if this prints something went wrong)
            else:
                print(f"Unable to delete the {file_path}")
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUIC, you can simply do this:

```py
import os

#paths to delete
paths = [r"C:\Users\jwals\test test", r"C:\Users\jwals\another test"]

def delete_files(path):
    #will check if the path is a dir or not
    if os.path.exists(path):
    
        #iterating through subfolders
        for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(path):
        
            #checking for files
            for file in files:
            
                #file path
                file_path = os.path.join(root_folder, file)
            
                ...

for path in paths:
    delete_files(path)
```